# Swift allow nil in a dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, option-type

I have a simple function like

```
func foo(a: String?, b:String, c: String){
    SomeClass.bla("param", props: [
       "a": a,
       "b": b,
       "c": c,
    ])
}
```

All I want is props to not contain `a` key if `a` is `nil` and to contain `a` with its String value(not optional) otherwise. Is there are nice way to do it inside the dictionary declaration?

The code I have of course doesn't work and I get `Value of optional type .. not unwrapped` error for `a`.

Comment: Where is `bar` declared?  And how is it defined?  What is its type?

Comment: You can create a dictionary of type `[String: String?]`, so it must be problem in the way you declare this bar()

Comment: There's also a problem with the syntax here: `bar(["a": a])`... what's that supposed to be doing?  Is `bar` a function somewhere?  You need to show more of your code and specify exactly which line is presenting the error.

Comment: i corrected the question a bit, does it make more sense now?

Answer (score 4):

Just create the dictionary as `var` and then add the `a` value. The subscript logic will add the `a` value only if it's not `nil`.

```
func foo(a:String?, b:String, c: String) {
    var dict = ["b": b, "c": c]
    dict["a"] = a
    SomeClass.bla("param", props: dict)
}
```

*Many thanks to @Sulthan for the elegant suggestion posted in the comment below.*

Comment: the funny thing, you don't need that `if let a = a` check. It's only the literal value where `nil` is a problem. `dict["a"] = nil` works just fine.

Comment: @Sulthan: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: `var dict = ["b": b, "c": c]`  `dict["a"] = a`. is enough. You don't need `if let a = a` condition.

Comment: @Sulthan: It won't compile if the `props` param of `SomeClass.bla` is defined as `[String:String]` since you are adding a `String?` as value.

Comment: It works because you can use subscript (`props[key] = nil`) to remove values from the dictionary. Just try it yourself.

Comment: @Sulthan: I'm sorry but I don't follow you. Could you please post the code?  I'm curious :)

Comment: already posted above. `var dict: [String: String] = ["b": b, "c": c]` `dict["a"] = a` is the whole code that is needed.

Comment: @Sulthan: you taught me something today. I really did not know that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ternary operator (?:)for the simple check you mentioned

```
func foo(a: String?){
    SomeClass.bla("param", props: a == nil ? [:] : [ "a": a! ]);
}
```

Since you **updated** your question the suitable solution would be:

```
func foo(a: String?, b:String, c: String){
    var props = [
        "b": b,
        "c": c,
    ]

    if let aValue = a {
        props["a"] = aValue
    }

    SomeClass.bla("param", props: props)
}
```

Comment: i have edited the question a bit, i have multiple params in the dict

Comment: yes, i have updated the answer for that situation as well